# Random numbers with a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, type-2-dimension

I'm working on an assignment for a class where I first need to declare integer array with 5 rows and 5 columns. Then initialize the array elements to random numbers between one and ten. The output is just a long list of 3 and nothing else. If you could point me in the right direction that would be very much appreciated.

I have to use this statement for random:

```
int r = (int)(Math.random()*(9-1+1))+1;
```

This is what I have so far and it's not working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
int[][] table= new int [5][5];
int r = (int)(Math.random()*(9-1+1))+1;

for(int row = 0; row < table.length; row++){
for(int column = 0; column < table[row].length; column++){
    table[row][column]=r;
    System.out.println(table[row][column]);
}
}

}

}
```

Comment: What are you achieving with "9-1+1"??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are calculating r before the loop,

```
int r = (int)(Math.random()*(9-1+1))+1;
```

all of the numbers in your table are goint to be the same.
Move this inside of the loop as such:

```
for(int row = 0; row < table.length; row++){
    for(int column = 0; column < table[row].length; column++){
        int r =(int)(Math.random()*(9-1+1))+1;
        table[row][column]=r;
        System.out.println(table[row][column]);
    }
}
```

#### PS.

`(int)(Math.random()*(9-1+1))+1;`

could probably be shortened to

`(int)(Math.random()*9)+1;`

Comment: Better to give him the idea and then let **him** create the code. Otherwise you're cheating him out of an opportunity to create his own code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the advice. I'm new to answering questions on StackOverflow so I will keep this in mind as I move forward.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do your randomization ***inside*** the for loop, not once before the for loop as you're doing it. This way, randomization will occur with **each iteration of the loop**.

Your code's logic in pseudo-code essentially is:

```
set r to a single random number
loop through the array 
   assign r (which never changes) to each item in the array
end loop
```

What you want to do is:

```
loop through the array
  create a new random r with each iteration of the loop 
  assign that r to an array element.
end loop
```

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> I want to print the output as a table with rows and columns.

Then you'll need to use nested for loops to do this. Either use the loop you've got, or create a new one to go through the array in a similar fashion. Understand that `System.out.print(...)` prints something to the screen while `System.out.println(...)` prints something and then starts a new line. You'll need to figure out where to use both of these methods.

Comment: That fixed the numbers, but it is still just printing as a list. Is that how it is supposed to print?

Comment: @user3720722: you will want to specify just what output you're looking for. Your question is somewhat anemic on this important detail.

Comment: I'm sorry. I want to print the output as a table with rows and columns.

Comment: @user3720722: Then you'll need to use nested for loops to do this. Either use the loop you've got, or create a new one to go through the array in a similar fashion. Understand that `System.out.print(...)` prints something to the screen while `System.out.println(...)` prints something and then starts a new line. You'll need to figure out where to use both of these methods.

Comment: So I'm just a little confused on using a nested loop for this. Am I to set up a loop for each individual row/column in order to print as a table?

Comment: @user3720722: chit man, you've already got nested for loops that already iterate through the array's rows and columns!

Comment: Yes, I realize that I've already used a nested loop. From your comment I thought you were suggesting to use another loop within my existing loop which was why I was confused. I realize that you meant just to adjust my print statement.

Comment: @user3720722: what I meant was, you could either use your current nested loop, or create a new one if desired, but if you create a new one, you already have the code that shows you how to do it, which is why I'm scratching my head over your recent question.